# Grails - Slow Deletions

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a Group domain object that contains a set of user domain objects
It is possible for this group object to have 200,000 users.

Whilst testing this, I noticed that deleting this group with groupModel.delete(flust:true) or even deleting all users on the group object groupModel.users.clear() when there were 200,000 users was very slow
The group domain object has cascade: 'all-delete-orphan' set for the users

Does anyone have any suggestions on how either of these delete operations can be sped up

Comment: What is it "slow" to you? Please, share a few numbers, otherwise it is difficult to help you out with this. Furthermore: which is the DBMS? have you put indexes properly?

Comment: Sorry lucke84 - oversight on my part. It was taking around 300 seconds to delete 200,000 records.

Comment: no worries at all. Anyways, follow Gregg suggestion and let us know how it goes. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't want to flush on each delete, that will be horribly slow.  Put the delete in a Service / Transaction and just do groupModel.delete().  Keep in mind that deleting 200,000 records plus all the cascades is going to take longer than say, 100 records.  But it will be faster if you let Hibernate worry about the flushing instead of forcing it.

Comment: thanks Gregg, that makes sense, i will try that out and let you know how I get on

Comment: @Damo Take a look at http://naleid.com/blog/2009/10/01/batch-import-performance-with-grails-and-mysql/. It should have similar implications for deleting.